# Changing meta facebook og with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a problem (obviously),
I've done a form that sends data in AJAX.
I get the return value from my request when it success and I append it in the og tag content.
for example

```
$('meta[property="title"]').attr('content', data.title);
```

after what when I check Elements in my chrome console, these changes are done.
But if i click on the Facebook share button, it doesn't care about my changes...
At the end , all what I want to change is the og tag title, description and image.

Any solutions ?
Thanks everyone.

Comment: You need to generate this HTML on the server side.  Facebook's HTML parser won't run script.

Comment: You mean I can't make it using AJAX ?
Damn..
or you mean I have to create my meta Element in php but I stil can use AJAX, but instead of set the meta og content i append the meta entierly ?

Comment: I mean Facebook will request the URL you give it using their own server, and parse whatever HTML that request spits out.  It will not run *any* script or do anything else.  You'll need to come up with an approach that works with this design.

Comment: Oh sure I understand, when I click on the FB share, it request the url I gave, but obviously it won't take care about my changes because it's a new request... ok so I just can't make it in AJAX like you said first, I should manage it on the server side.
THX Mike for your help.

Comment: You should make a real answer I could mark it as resolved ;)

Comment: Done!  I appreciate it.

Comment: Please note that hte "approach that works with this design" is the one i gave earlier :P

Comment: Haha yes Bene that was the idea but not the answer I was looking for but thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a page is *Liked* or *referenced* on Facebook, Facebook requests the URL from *their end*, downloads the HTML, and parses it using a *very* simplified HTML parser that looks for OpenGraph tags.

For this reason, only the HTML generated directly by the server will be seen by Facebook.  Any JavaScript embedded in the HTML will not get run, nor will any resources referenced by the page be loaded.

You'll need to figure out some way to communicate the information by manipulating the URL; such as adding URL parameters, assigning a permalink to the content, using re-write rules on the web server, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One URL can only have one opengraph description. BUT, you can add some variable in order to change the opengraph tags according to the content. Let's say you have a page www.example.com and wanna share some entities. If you have a user, you can share www.example.com?user=[id] and set the server side code to do this:

```
if (isset($_GET['user'])) {
   // Opengraph for user
   // Perhaps you wanna load the user and show his infos.
}
if (isset($_GET['team'])) {
   // opengraph for team
}
else {
   // Default opengraph
}
```

Don't forget that the opengraph IMAGE must be IN THE DOM. You can always add

```
<div style="display: none;">
<img src="[path to the shared image]" />
</div>
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks it's useful but not exactly what I was asking for.
I should vote up if I could ;)